# How to Escape comma(,) in string selected value javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hello i am trying to escape comma(,) in a string.and i am using split and join when i select multiple values.But in some cases within my selection i have comma(,) so it is considering that as different string.How i can escape comma in selection.

What i am trying is

```
$('#info').on('rowselect', function (event) {

  var rows = $("#info").jqxGrid('selectedrowindexes');

  var selectedvalue = new Array();
  if (rows != "") {
    for (var m = 0; m < rows.length; m++) {
      var row = $("#info").jqxGrid('getrowdata', rows[m]);

      selectedvalue [selectedvalue .length] = row;
    }

    var len = selectedvalue .length;

    var data = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

      data += selectedvalue[i].fieldvale +",";

    }

    var newStr = data.substring(0, data.length - 1);

    var finalOutput = newStr.split(',');

    var fieldvale = "" + finalOutput.join("','") + "";

    GetGidbyplots($('#ddlIndustrialarea').find('option:selected').text(), fieldvale);
  }
});
```

My selection values are like :**'10','11','12','117,142&141'**

Comment: How do you decide when to select and when not to?

Comment: Can you please make it a bit clear?

Comment: It looks like you have an array of values, which you then concat into a string (separated by commas), then split the string on your comma.. then join it back again? Can you explain what problem you are having in better detail, and at which step.

Comment: @daniel_ZA No i have not tried,but for For function i have to pass value with comma if it contains comma for ex:'117,142&141' is single value.'

Comment: Hi @Ashley'CptLemming'Wilson:When i pass parameter to function the one value is splitting into two like '117','142&141' like this.but is single value only.'

Comment: @vihika and if you use the HTML enitity `&#44;` instead?

Comment: @Daniel_ZA No i am not getting HTML entity.

Comment: Use a different delimiter in your calculations ($/;/:) so that it doesn't confuse with `,` delimiter already used.

Comment: @sabithpocker Thanks for help.IT is working for me.when i use different delimeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working Solution is

```
$('#info').on('rowselect', function (event) {

            var rows = $("#info").jqxGrid('selectedrowindexes');

            var selectedvalue = new Array();
            if (rows != "") {
                for (var m = 0; m < rows.length; m++) {
                    var row = $("#info").jqxGrid('getrowdata', rows[m]);

                    selectedvalue [selectedvalue .length] = row;
                }

                var len = selectedvalue .length;

                var data = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                    data += selectedvalue[i].fieldvale +":";

                }

                var newStr = data.substring(0, data.length - 1);

                var finalOutput = newStr.split(':');

                var fieldvale = "" + finalOutput.join("','") + "";

                GetGidbyplots($('#ddlIndustrialarea').find('option:selected').text(), fieldvale);
            }
        });
```